# React router doesn't work in my private admin layout and normal user layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new at react and I want to show my admin dashboard privately whit Route but just first Route work and the other Route's component don't shown. this is my code:

```
<Routes>
      <Route path="/admin" element={<PrivateLayout />}>
        <Route path="/dashboard" exact element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Route>

      <Route exact path='/' element={<MainLayouts />}>
        <Route  path="/" element={<Course />} />
        <Route  path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route  path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route  path="/course/:id" element={<SingleCourse />} />
        <Route  path="/archive" element={<Archive />} />
        <Route  path="/logout" element={<Logout />} />
        <Route  path="*"  element={<NotFound />} />
      </Route>

    </Routes>
```

by the mean just PrivateLayout in path of '/dashboard' and the MainLayouts in the path of '/' shown and login, register , ... dont shown in their own path.

and also MainLayouts codes are:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Header from "./../common/headers";
import TopNav from "./../Navs/TopNav";
import MainNav from "./../Navs/MainNav";
import Footer from './../common/Footers';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';

const MainLayouts = ({children}) => {
  
  const location = useLocation()
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="landing-layer">
        <div className="container">
          <TopNav />
          {location.pathname === "/" ? <Header /> : null}
        </div>
      </div>

      <MainNav />

      <main id="home-page">
              <div className="container">{children}</div>
      </main>

      <Footer/>
 
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default MainLayouts;
```

and PrivateLayout codes are:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import AdminTopNav from "../admin/AdminTopNav";
import AdminSidebar from "../admin/AdminSidebar";

const PrivateLayout = ({ children }) => {
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    return (
        <div id="wrapper">
            <Helmet>
                <title> dashboard </title>
            </Helmet>
            <nav
                className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"
                role="navigation"
            >
                <div className="navbar-header">
                    <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/dashboard">
                        admin dashboard
                    </Link>
                </div>

                <AdminTopNav user={user} />

                <AdminSidebar />
            </nav>
            <div id="page-wrapper">{children}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PrivateLayout;
```

Comment: Can you include all relevant code? The `PrivateLayout` and `MainLayouts` components code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Other than `"/dashboard"` not being a valid route under the `"/admin"` route I don't see much issue with the code.

Comment: yes sir why not? I add my MainLayouts and PrivateLayout code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that your layout components are rendering the children prop instead of an `Outlet` component for the nested `Route` components to be rendered into. I also found the use of the `Outlet` component confusing when upgrading from `react-router-dom@5`.

[Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their
> child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child
> routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will
> render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

`Outlet` components are commonly used in what are called layout routes.

[Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes)

## Solution

Replace the rendering of the `children` prop with the `Outlet` component.

```
import { Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router';

const MainLayouts = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="landing-layer">
        <div className="container">
          <TopNav />
          {location.pathname === "/" ? <Header /> : null}
        </div>
      </div>

      <MainNav />

      <main id="home-page">
        <div className="container">
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </main>

      <Footer/>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default MainLayouts;
```

...

```
import { Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateLayout = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      <Helmet>
        <title> dashboard </title>
      </Helmet>
      <nav
        className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"
        role="navigation"
      >
        <div className="navbar-header">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/dashboard">
            admin dashboard
          </Link>
        </div>

        <AdminTopNav user={user} />

        <AdminSidebar />
      </nav>
      <div id="page-wrapper">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PrivateLayout;
```

Once the layout routes are rendering an `Outlet` component you'll see why `"/dashboard"` isn't a valid path under `"/admin"`.

> ## Error
>
> Absolute route path "/dashboard" nested under path "/admin" is not
> valid. An absolute child route path must start with the combined path
> of all its parent routes.

I will assume at this point you want all the `"/admin"` routes to be nested under it, so use either absolute path `"/admin/dashboard"` or relative path `"dashboard"`.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/admin" element={<PrivateLayout />}>
    <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
  </Route>

  <Route path="/" element={<MainLayouts />}>
    <Route index element={<Course />} />
    <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
    <Route path="course/:id" element={<SingleCourse />} />
    <Route path="archive" element={<Archive />} />
    <Route path="logout" element={<Logout />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-router-doesnt-work-in-my-private-admin-layout-and-normal-user-layout]